# OpenSUSE - Apple Wireless Keyboard - Switch "fn" and "ctrl" key?

Tags: opensuse, keyboard, xmodmap, apple

I'm trying to configure the Apple Keyboard so that the "fn" key and the "ctrl" key are swapped. So far I swapped the "cmd" and "alt" key, the "°" and "<" key using xmodmap. Information for that can be found comparatively easy.

Unfortunately xev does not give any output for the fn key, for all the other's it does.

Does anybody have a solution for that, without me having to recompile my own kernel (this is a machine from work so I can't change the system, though I can do whatever I want in the user space). The solution with recompiling the kernel can be found here: [Linux: Apple Wireless A1314 Fn key not registered, looks like software bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41537/linux-apple-wireless-a1314-fn-key-not-registered-looks-like-software-bug)

My kernel is the 2.6.37.6-0.20-desktop kernel from the OpenSUSE repository, under a OpenSUSE 11.04 32bit.

Update: I found out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/451398/is-there-a-way-to-remap-the-fn-and-ctrl-keys-on-an-apple-wireless-keyboard/485738#485738), that the fn-key has the keycode 464 (showkeys detects it). Unfortunately this is bigger than 255 which means it can appearently not be mapped with xmodmap.

Comment: You can [remap the keys with keycode > 255 using `udev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170357/245377), which I believe SuSE should also support.