# keyboard hard remap keys?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, key-mapping

I am trying to find a way to remap keyboard keys forcefully.
I tried using xmodmap and setxkbmap, but they do not work for one specific application. Such commands work for other normal windowed/applications on X tho.

I think the application may be reading the keyboard raw data and ignoring X input?

**So, how to remap keys without using xmodmap and setxkbmap? if it is ever possible to be done using some software.**

I also tried xkeycaps, xkbcomp, but did not try loadkeys, as it is running on X.

I found [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=55029) that I could try `setkeycodes`, ["because after assigning kernel keycode the button should work in xorg"](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=33831), but I also found that ["you can't use 'setkeycodes' on USB keyboards"](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/552842), that's my case (I am interested in case someone make it work on ps2 as I think I could use an adapter).

This seemed promising ["Map scancodes to keycodes"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes), but after a few tests nothing changed, here are they:
I found keycode "36" ("j" key) at vt1 with `showkey`
I found scancode "7e" (keypad ".") at vt1 with `showkey --scancodes`

```
$cat >/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-custom-keyboard.hwdb
keyboard:usb:v*p*
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7e=36
$udevadm hwdb --update #updates file: /lib/udev/hwdb.bin
$udevadm trigger #should apply the changes but nothing happened
$cat /lib/udev/hwdb.bin |egrep "KEYBOARD_KEY_7e.{10}" -ao
KEYBOARD_KEY_7eleftmeta
$#that cat on hwdb.bin did not change after the commands..
```

Obs.: did not work either with: `KEYBOARD_KEY_7e=j`

Some more alternative ways (by @vinc17) to find the keys:
`evtest /dev/input/by-id/...`  or
`input-kbd 3` (put the id index found at `ls -l /dev/input/by-id/*` from ex. event3)

PS.: *If you are interested on testing yourself, the related thread for the application is this:   http://forums.thedarkmod.com/topic/14266-keyboard-issue-in-new-version-108/ The issues I have are the same: some keys (KP_Decimal, DownArrow, UpArrow, RightArrow) are ignored and considered all with the same value there "0x00"

Comment: The updated file should be `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin`, not `/lib/udev/hwdb.bin`. But though this file is updated correctly, this doesn't work for me either, even after a reboot. Perhaps something missing in the documentation. About this: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82311

Comment: @vinc17 that is really interesting, as soon I can I will try again, I think we have to find that settings file and try to imitate it, thx!

Comment: My problem was due to the fact that the KEYBOARD_KEY_ lines started with 2 spaces instead of a single one (this wasn't documented and I got no error messages!). I don't know for you, but with my USB keyboard, `showkey --scancodes` doesn't give the scancodes udev expects (the values are different); the `input-kbd` utility gives the correct scancodes.

Comment: The `evtest` utility should also give you the correct scancodes: after typing a key, you should get 2 lines and the first one should end with something of the form `code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value xxx`, where `xxx` is the scancode. But the driver for my keyboard is buggy, and I don't get this `MSC_SCAN` line for some keys I wanted to remap. That's why I used `input-kbd`, which lists all the scancodes for the selected device.

Comment: interesting, I had none of these applications hehe! so it did work for you right? mind pasting the code? btw, at `evtest` the value for my keypad "." shows as 70085. I tried with this: KEYBOARD_KEY_70085=36, KEYBOARD_KEY_70085=7002c (7002c is the code of space bar btw); I tried with 1 space, 2 spaces and a TAB before that line at configuration file, none worked, may be I am still missing the right way to configure/type it? it show no error messages either..

Comment: I've posted detailed info in an answer. Now, I'm not sure that 36 or 7002c works as a value. I think that you need the key code identifier. See my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First find the scancode of the key that needs to be remapped, e.g. with the `evtest` utility. A line like the following one (with `MSC_SCAN` in it) should be output:

```
Event: time 1417131619.686259, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70068
```

followed by a second one giving the current key code. If no `MSC_SCAN` line is output, this is due to a kernel driver bug, but the scancode can still be found with the `input-kbd` utility; `evtest` should have given the key code, so that it should be easy to find the corresponding line in the `input-kbd` output (e.g. by using `grep`).

Once the scancodes of the keys to be remapped have been determined, create a file such as `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/98-custom-keyboard.hwdb` containing the remappings. The beginning of the file `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` gives some information. In my case (which works), I have:

```
evdev:input:b0003v05ACp0221*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70035=102nd       # Left to z: backslash bar
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70064=grave       # Left to 1: grave notsign
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70068=insert      # F13: Insert
```

(Before udev 220, I had to use `keyboard:usb:v05ACp0221*` for the first line.)

The `evdev:` string must be at the beginning of the line.
Note that the letters in the vendor and product id should be capital letters.
Each `KEYBOARD_KEY_` settings should have exactly one space before (note: a line with no spaces will give an error message, and a line with two spaces were *silently* ignored with old udev versions). `KEYBOARD_KEY_` is followed by the scancode in hexadecimal (like what both `evtest` and `input-kbd` give). Valid values could be obtained from either the `evtest` output or the `input-kbd` output, or even from the `/usr/include/linux/input.h` file: for instance, `KEY_102ND` would give `102nd` (by removing `KEY_` and converting to lower case), which I used above.

After the file is saved, type:

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

to (re)build the database `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` (you can check its timestamp). Then,

```
udevadm trigger --sysname-match="event*"
```

will take the new settings into account. You can check with `evtest`.

In 2014, the released udev had incomplete/buggy information in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`, but you can look at [the latest development version of the file](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/hwdb/60-keyboard.hwdb) and/or [my bug report and discussion](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82311) concerning the documentation and spacing issues.

If this doesn't work, the problem might be found after temporarily increasing the log level of `udevd` with `udevadm control` (see the udevadm(8) man page for details).

For old `udev` versions such as 204, [this method](https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.en.html#udev) should still work.

Comment: When I run the udevadm commands, the file that gets updated is `/lib/udev/hwdb.bin`, I looked with `bless` and the `KEYBOARD_KEY_70085` appears at its end. I think ubuntu 14.04 is configured (protected?) this way. I tried `udevadm control --log-priority=debug`. based on `lsusb` (045e:0750) my keyboard gets like `keyboard:usb:v045ep0750*`, but I tried with `keyboard:usb:v*p*` too. My guess is this `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` should be updated but doesnt even exist.

Comment: As I read [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udevadm.html) it could be like I was using this command `udevadm hwdb --usr --update`, despite I was not.

Comment: After `udevadm hwdb --update` I copied `/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` to `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` and ran `strace udevadm trigger --sysname-match="event*"` and the file `hwdb.bin` seems have not been read by it (if it is like this works).

Comment: as it works for you, my guess is my system is bugged (as this functionality seems somewhat bugged), as soon I can, I will see if I can upgrade my packages and may be this can work! my `udevadm --version` is 204 btw.

Comment: @AquariusPower Yes, there may be an Ubuntu specific bug (I'm using Debian/unstable). To see whether the database is read when doing `udevadm trigger ...`, see [my test here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82311#c6). Note that before running `udevadm trigger ...`, you need to make sure that the modification time of the file has been updated, otherwise the access time will not be updated when the file is read.

Comment: will check the test (btw I would like to link [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33038/how-to-get-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000s-zoom-slider-and-other-bu))

Comment: oh, while I was testing, I checked if the hwdb.bin was being updated with `bless` hexeditor; I saw at its end the `KEYBOARD_KEY_70085` that I was trying to remap had been written there. And that file had its timestamp updated! :). it really looks like a bug or a limitation here. What is your `udevadm --version`?

Comment: btw, I did not reboot as I need this to be changeable without rebooting, on the fly. May be this is intended to only work with a reboot?

Comment: @AquariusPower `udevadm --version`: 215 (and udev package version: 215-7). Thanks to `udevadm trigger ...`, you shouldn't need to reboot (unless you want to remove settings, AFAIK). But you may want to try a reboot to see if there is any effect.

Comment: I think that is it, on my system the highest version possible to install thru package manager is 204! [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=udev&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) I found that 215 is the latest `udev` and is on the `ubuntu vivid` that unfortunately is not LTS. I have to think on this, may be a version between 204 and 215 may work and is installable without too much trouble here. May be also a fix may be provided for this 204 old version too! Thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower I've added an alternate method at the end of my answer for old udev versions.

Comment: cool, I created this file `/etc/udev/keymaps/mykeymaps.cfg`  with `0x70085 grave`, and this file `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-my-custom-keyboard.rules` with `ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="045e", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0750", RUN+="keymap $name /etc/udev/keymaps/mykeymaps.cfg"`; I saw on the README that udev should monitor and apply such rules but nothing happened yet, any idea? any way to force/check if it is being read/applied?

Comment: @AquariusPower I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Still nothing after reboot? This method worked very well for me under Debian up to udev 204, and when I upgraded to udev 215, I had to use the new hwdb method. Check in `dmesg` output that there's a "New USB device found" line corresponding to your idVendor/idProduct. If not, this may be a kernel/driver bug. Otherwise you should see with a udev developer.

Comment: yes, I found it on `dmesg` and with `lsusb`, I think my kernel or driver is buggy or there is something else that ubuntu does to protect the system from being easily tweaked like that :/. As soon I can I will try a boot with a liveCD that has udev 215+ and see what happens :D.

Comment: oh btw, I would like to add that after reboot, the udev 204 says that `/etc/udev/keymaps/mykeymaps.cfg` was not found! that seems a serious bug or may be it should be configured in some other undocumented way... Anyway, I think messing too much with a buggy app is not good idea unless on critical situations; better is try to update it as soon I can...

Comment: Note that is is necessary to use the format `evdev:input:b*v*p*` since v220. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216811/168688

Comment: Question: What's the difference between `KEYBOARD_KEY_70039` from `MSC_SCAN, value 70039` and `KEYBOARD_KEY_58` from `code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)`? They seem to achieve the same effects?

Comment: Note that when using evtest to get the scancodes, the value of the EV_MSC,MSC_SCAN line is the scancode, and the value of the EV_KEY line (the next/second line) is the keycode, and the hwdb rule maps scancodes (former) to keycodes (latter). I got confused because my USB keyboard gave scancodes in the form of "70032", while my laptop gave me scancodes of the form "1d". I must have tested wrong, and KEYBOARD_KEY_58 shouldn't have worked.

Comment: @MichaelYoo Thanks for the reminder about the change in udev 220; I've now updated my answer (I forgot to do this when I updated my config). 70039 is here the scancode, and 58 (event code) is the keycode; for instance, you can use "58" instead of "capslock" (in the past, I had to use "86" instead of "102nd" due to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=654947)). Note that the scancodes depend on the keyboard.

Comment: I used `evdev:input:b*v*p*` directly so I did not need to figure out the specific values to fill in to identify my keyboard.

Comment: For the `evdev:input:bZZZZvYYYYpXXXX`, `ZZZZ`, `YYYY` and `XXXX` and are the 4-digit hex uppercase bus, vendor and product ID (they are explained in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`). To obtain these values of your keyboard, first use `evtest` to identify the event number `eventX` of it, then check files under `/sys/class/input/eventX/device/id/`.

Comment: finally, I retried this on ubuntu 20.04 and worked great, thx!! I created this example if it can help: https://gist.github.com/AquariusPower/83748456a59ea743ae034ed78b14f646