# Udev hwdb rule does not work

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, systemd, udev

I am switching from Ubuntu to Arch Linux and encountering the issue that a udev hwdb rule that has worked until now does not work anymore. The only obvious difference between the systems is that Ubuntu uses udev version 219 and Arch uses udev version 221.

I have the following contents in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-logitech-m560.hwdb` on both systems:

```
keyboard:usb:v046DpC52B*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_90004=left
 KEYBOARD_KEY_90005=right
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70007=back
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700E7=forward
```

On Ubuntu it worked after executing `udevadm hwdb --update` and rebooting.

However on Arch, I have executed the command `udevadm hwdb --update` (multiple times) und rebooted (also multiple times) and also tested `udevadm trigger` and `udevadm control --reload` as suggested by other answers here but nothing has worked so far. **So my question is: How do I get this udev rule to work in Arch Linux?**

This is the evdev output on Ubuntu (where it works):

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0x402d version 0x111
Input device name: "Logitech M560"
Supported events:
Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 150 (KEY_WWW)
    Event code 152 (KEY_SCREENLOCK)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 176 (KEY_EDIT)
    Event code 177 (KEY_SCROLLUP)
    Event code 178 (KEY_SCROLLDOWN)
    Event code 179 (KEY_KPLEFTPAREN)
    Event code 180 (KEY_KPRIGHTPAREN)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 277 (BTN_FORWARD)
    Event code 278 (BTN_BACK)
    Event code 279 (BTN_TASK)
    Event code 280 (?)
    Event code 281 (?)
    Event code 282 (?)
    Event code 283 (?)
    Event code 284 (?)
    Event code 285 (?)
    Event code 286 (?)
    Event code 287 (?)
Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML)
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL)
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL)
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE)
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA)
Key repeat handling:
Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
    Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
    Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1437136178.466244, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e7
Event: time 1437136178.466244, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1437136178.466244, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1437136178.590240, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e7
Event: time 1437136178.590240, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1437136178.590240, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

And this is on Arch (where the remapping does not work):

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0x402d version 0x111
Input device name: "Logitech M560"
Supported events:
Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 150 (KEY_WWW)
    Event code 152 (KEY_SCREENLOCK)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 176 (KEY_EDIT)
    Event code 177 (KEY_SCROLLUP)
    Event code 178 (KEY_SCROLLDOWN)
    Event code 179 (KEY_KPLEFTPAREN)
    Event code 180 (KEY_KPRIGHTPAREN)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 275 (BTN_SIDE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
    Event code 277 (BTN_FORWARD)
    Event code 278 (BTN_BACK)
    Event code 279 (BTN_TASK)
    Event code 280 (?)
    Event code 281 (?)
    Event code 282 (?)
    Event code 283 (?)
    Event code 284 (?)
    Event code 285 (?)
    Event code 286 (?)
    Event code 287 (?)
Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML)
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL)
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL)
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE)
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA)
Key repeat handling:
Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
    Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
    Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1437143765.953616, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e7
Event: time 1437143765.953616, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1437143765.953616, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1437143766.063653, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e7
Event: time 1437143766.063653, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1437143766.063653, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

Comment: What command did you get the output of the `Event code` list from?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, udev has changed the way it matches hardware in v220, which means that it was necessary to change

```
keyboard:usb:v046DpC52B*
```

to

```
evdev:input:b0003v046Dp402D*
```

(the `b0003` is the bus-id of USB)

What irritates me is that another product ID is now needed. Before v220, the ID `C52B` was used for all parts of the device (a multi-button mouse), however now I need the ID `402D` to address the keyboard. `evtest` already showed this ID in Ubuntu, but the old rule worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have my keyboard configuration from Debian Jessie. it's not working out of box for Arch, too.
After having a quick look at `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`, I found **replacing**:
`keyboard` to `evdev:atkbd` works for me.