# How to make SysRq working on laptop?

Tags: linux-kernel, keyboard-layout, magic-sysrq

My `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` contains the number 502, but Alt+SysRq+... seems not to work on my HP Pavilion laptop. How can I fix that?

Update 1: By the way: neither my print-screen-key nor any other key has an additional label like "SysRq".

Update 2:

- Hardware model: HP Pavilion 17 Notebook PC
- Keyboard layout: German, QWERTZ

Comment: Seems not to work.

Comment: What exact laptop model do you have, and what keyboard layout? Which keys have you tried?

Comment: I've tried the print-screen-key with and without Fn and with and without CapsLock.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most laptops require pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> to get the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> usually doesn't affect the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (at least the left one) but may affect the letter that you press after <kbd>SysRq</kbd>. Fortunately, you don't need to press <kbd>SysRq</kbd> and the third key together, it's enough to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down. The following sequence works on all the laptops I've seen:

1. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>, press the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key, and release both.
3. Briefly the letter or punctuation key, e.g. <kbd>S</kbd> to sync.
4. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

The <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key is usually the same key as <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>. If your keyboard doesn't have a key labeled <kbd>SysRq</kbd> or <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, it may not have a key that sends the scan code that Linux expects. For the purpose of magic SysRq, the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key is whichever key sends the scan code 99.

With a PS/2 keyboard (including a laptop's internal keyboard), to find out what scan code a key sends, log into a text console (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text console, and usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the GUI), and run the command [`showkey -s`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey). `showkey -s` displays the scan code of each key as you type it. That's usually one byte (two hexadecimal digits) for a key press, then another byte for the key release. For a few keys, you'll get a byte sequence consisting of two bytes starting with `e0`. Press the key you're interested in, then wait 10 seconds and `showkey` will exit.

Now that you've identified a scan code, run [`setkeycodes … 99`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setkeycodes) as root to assign that scan code to key code 99. For example, if `showkey -s` prints `0xe0 0x6f 0xe0 0xef` for the key you've chosen, run `setkeycodes e06f 99`.

To make this change permanent, either add the `setkeycodes` command to `/etc/rc.local`, or [configure udev to change the keycode mappings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156985/keyboard-hard-remap-keys). Configuring udev is the only solution for a USB keyboard, `setkeycodes` doesn't affect USB keyboards.

Comment: Seems not to work.

Comment: @AlKlimov You need to press the SysRq key. If your keyboard doesn't have a SysRq key, that's obviously a problem. See my edited answer.

Comment: I couldn't turn my PrintScreen key, but I could turn e.g. my F12 key. Strange, strange..

Comment: Genius! I tried with and without the fn keys so many times, but never thought to hybrid it up with your approach.  Thanks!

Comment: I get: `setkeycodes: failed to set scancode 90 to keycode 99: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument`.  Unfortunately I have an Apple keyboard on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a newer HP pavilion Laptop, same issue.
What worked for me, was pressing the AltGr key with the printscreen key